# How to disable default player on Android Wear

Tags: android-notifications, wear-os

Is there a way to disable default player notification from showing up on Android Wear?

EDIT:
If yes, how can I disable it both programmatically and manually on a device?

Comment: What do you mean by default player notification?

Comment: The notification which shows up on wear when you start playing music on your phone (without any additional code of yours)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I am pretty noobish with stack, so it might be.. Do I need to ask all Android-related questions there?

Comment: @scloune The questions allowed on SO are [detailed in the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). As long as your problem is not directly related to programming there is usually a site on stackexchange that is better suited.

Comment: @scloune Do you want to know how to disable the player notifications programmatically from your own Java code, or disable the notification for an existing application installed to your phone?

Comment: @Wayne I don't understand your questions. I want to know how to disable it in both ways if possible (programmatically and manually).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the app that is doing this is Google Play Music, so you'll want to mute that app. Here's how you do it:

1. Open Android Wear on your phone
2. Click on the gears icon at the top
3. Select "Mute app notifications"
4. Click on the "+" button and select Google Play Music

This will also work for other apps if you want to mute notifications from them.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done. It is inbuilt into Android Wear, or indeed the Android Wear App, or Google Play Services.  From [here](https://support.google.com/androidwear/answer/6056843?hl=en-GB):

> When you listen to music on your phone, you’ll always see the music card with options to pause and play. You can’t turn this card off.

It must detect that music is playing, and send details to the watch, and display an on-going notification (no Mute App button available!).

Very annoying.